# put matrices into an empty cell using matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have four 2*2 matrices called m1,m2,m3,m4. I want to create an empty 2*2 cell array which every element of it will be also 2*2 matrices. Then I want to put m1(1,1) & m2(1,1) & m3(1,1) & m4(1,1) elements into that created empty cell matrices so that element (1,1) of them will be that m1(1,1) & m2(1,1) & m3(1,1) & m4(1,1) s. And again do it again for next remaind elements as I said.

Can anyone help me do this with matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anything crazy, just `reshape` and `num2cell`

```
c = reshape(num2cell([m1(:), m2(:), m3(:), m4(:)], 2), size(m1));
```

I think this is a good general way to do it.

Edit: 2015/07/25 14:45

Based on your comments it seems like what you have is a cell array

```
M = {m1, m2, ..., mn}
```

I think you're saying that each m is 2x2, but I'll assume it's `q`x`r`

And you want to get it in the form,

```
c = {[m1(1,1), m2(1,1), ..., mn(1,1)], [m1(1,2), m2(1,2), ..., mn(1,2)], ..., [m1(1,q), m1(1,q), ..., mn(1,q)]
     [m1(2,1), m2(2,1), ..., mn(2,1)], [m1(2,2), m2(2,2), ..., mn(2,2)], ..., [m1(2,q), m1(2,q), ..., mn(2,q)]
     ...
     [m1(r,1), m2(r,1), ..., mn(r,1)], [m1(r,2), m2(r,2), ..., mn(r,2)], ..., [m1(r,q), m1(r,q), ..., mn(r,q)]}
```

If all this is accurate, then the code you need is

```
c = reshape(num2cell(cell2mat(cellfun(@(m) m(:), M(:)', 'uni', 0)), 2), size(M{1}));
```

So a good way to test this is to make a `M`, then run the code

```
M = arrayfun(@(i) randi(100, 7, 3), 1:14, 'uni', 0);
c = reshape(num2cell(cell2mat(cellfun(@(m) m(:), M(:)', 'uni', 0)), 2), size(M{1}));
```

the only new piece compared to the above code is the `cell2mat(cellfun(@(m) m(:), M(:)', 'uni', 0))`. This takes `M` (which is a cell array of matrices) and first turns it into a cell array of column vectors (by the `cellfun`). It then concatenates those columns into a matrix which each row is a `m1(i,j), m2(i,j), ...` set. Then like before we split each row into its own cell of a cell array, then `reshape` it so it's the same size as one of the `m`'s.

Comment: thanks for you help. how can I edit this code for unknown number of  m matrices? I mean here I have four m matrices called m1,m2,m3,m4 but in my general code due to the input number of blocks we may have 4,8,16... number of them.

Comment: First off, if you're going to have an arbitrary number of matrices you should look into using a cell array. But if that's not an option you can do it the way that will get you dirty looks. `n = 16; c = reshape(num2cell(eval(['[', strjoin(arrayfun(@(i) strcat('m', num2str(i), '(:)'), (1:n), 'uni', 0), ' '), ']', ]), 2), size(m1));`

Comment: yes I have a 1*4 cell array which its elements are that m matrices and I want to reshape them in the way that I said above but as I said, that cell array elements are not fixed 4 matrices and based on input block number I may have 8,16.... number of them.  I pasted you code but it gives error on 'strjoin'  because my input value is cell how can I change it for cell array input?

Comment: I don't know why the `eval` statement didn't work. I created a set of `m` matrices like you described. `n = 16; eval(strjoin(arrayfun(@(i) strcat('m', num2str(i), ' = rand(2); '), (1:n), 'uni', 0), ' '));`. Then I ran the code I posted `c = reshape(num2cell(eval(['[', strjoin(arrayfun(@(i) strcat('m', num2str(i), '(:)'), (1:n), 'uni', 0), ' '), ']', ]), 2), size(m1));` and it worked fine.

Comment: See edits. The code I think you need is `c = reshape(num2cell(cell2mat(cellfun(@(m) m(:), M(:)', 'uni', 0)), 2), size(M{1}));`

Comment: Thankkkk you so much this code is exacly what I want!!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a pure syntax problem.

```
c = cell(4,4);  %Create the empty cell
c{1,1} = [m1(1,1) m2(1,1); m3(1,1) m4(1,1)]; Put a constructed 2x2 matrix in position 1,1
c{1,2} = [m1(1,2) m2(1,2); m3(1,2) m4(1,2)]; 
c{2,1} = [m1(2,1) m2(2,1); m3(2,1) m4(2,1)]; 
c{2,2} = [m1(2,2) m2(2,2); m3(2,2) m4(2,2)];
```

If you want, (e.g. if your actual problem is a much bigger size) you can do the same thing in loops. There may even be a clever `arrayfun` solution. But nothing will be faster.

Comment: YES my exact problem is that these matrices change in number but I dont know how to do that. I will be thankfull if you help me with that case so.